# Installing react-redux in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, asset-pipeline, redux

I am building a React app in Rails and would like to try `react-redux`. I noticed that it doesn't offer a CDN nor a bower package.

The installation instructions recommend using NPM, but this is not a node project. I handle all my current assets through the Rails asset pipeline, a CDN or a bower package (via [rails-assets](https://rails-assets.org/))

- Is there a way to install it without using NPM?
- Is there a way to get NPM packages to play nice with existing asset pipeline packages?

Comment: You can help by sending a PR to `cdnjs` to include `react-redux`: https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/issues/76#issuecomment-144015493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that it is possible using `react-rails` in conjunction with `browserify-rails`. [This blog article](http://ttrmw.co.uk/code/rails_and_react_with_npm_modules.html) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 10):

You can also check out https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails. It's integrated with webpack which gives it a nice and familiar javascript flow.

They've also got a live example at http://www.reactrails.com/ and the code for that at https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command `yarn add redux react-redux`
This will add redux and react-redux to dependency as well as connect react to redux.
I am using rails 6 and it works fine with this.

> add ruby related lib via `bundle` add and js related lib via `yarn`